# Laravel multi language route for multiple pages

Tags: php, laravel, localization, laravel-routing, multilingual

I have a project which contains many pages. I have added language picker drop down menu to change the language. The language change is working perfectly but I want to make the URL  like `/dashboard?lang=en` or `/dashboard/?lang=en` or `/customer/settings?lang=en`. Can I just use one route to make changes in language for all the sub pages? I have set two languages. Everything is working with the drop down button but not the URL. I want to know how to reflect the language change in the url. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I recommend you save the language in the session instead. So when the request has the parameter `lang=en`, you put `en` in the session and have a middleware set the locale based on that parameter.

Comment: Wouldn't `App::setLocale(\Input::get('lang'))` work for query parameters?

Comment: https://youtu.be/HeIZ412laoU see tutorial here

Answer (score 2):

Instead of query parameters, a common method is to use a route prefix in your URLs like:

```
https://example.com/en/home
https://example.com/es/home
https://example.com/fr/home
```

Then you can setup route groups based on the localization prefix:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => app()->locale()], function() { ... });
```

Or, use as a route parameter:

```
Route::get('{locale}/home', function ($locale) {
    App::setLocale($locale);

    // add routes...
});
```

Comment: my route for the drop down button is Route::get('lang/{lang}', function($lang) {
  \Session::put('lang', $lang);
  return \Redirect::back();
})->middleware('web')->name('change_lang');
is there any way i can connect it to change the url?